# Is the Hubble parameter affected by 'peculiar velocity'?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

Are there any direct observations showing the effect of peculiar velocity on the Hubble parameter.  If the Hubble parameter is measured in the direction of our motion caused by our rotation in the milky way, is it the same as its observed value when measured in a direction perpendicular to this motion?

Comment: What kind of observations? Obviously there is a big dipole signal in the cosmic microwave background. Are you just asking whether that is duplicated in galaxy redshift surveys?

Comment: There are peculiar red shifts which aren't alignment issues. For instance, if you calculate the rotational velocity and the rotation diameter based on the morphology of the galaxy, for M81 and the spiral galaxy NGC-309, and then place them at their red shift distances, M81 is a smudge on one of the spirals arm of NGC-309. And based on NGC-309's huge size, then there should be roughly a super nova every Blue Moon. This may be intrinsic red shift problem with spiral galaxies - and especially quasars.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Hubble diagram below. Obviously, not all the galaxies lie on the straight line, presumably because of a non-zero peculiar velocity. But we hope that the peculiar velocities have a uniform angular distribution, so cancel out upon averaging/linear regression.

FYI, there are galaxies which are *blue-shifted* relative to us, as we are attracted to them due to the dark-matter content. <strike>Search for the M98 galaxy.</strike> See M31 (Andromeda) galaxy, our nearest neighbour.

[image]

Comment: "FYI, there are galaxies which are blue-shifted relative to us, as we are attracted to them due to the dark-matter content. Search for the M98 galaxy." Since M98 is a member of the Virgo cluster, its peculiar velocity is no-doubt influenced much more by its closer neighbors than by our own galaxy. And what does dark matter have to do with it?

Comment: " Obviously, not all the galaxies lie on the straight line, presumably because of a non-zero peculiar velocity. " If the scatter in the data were primarily due to the peculiar velocities, then you would expect the scatter to get smaller with increasing redshift, but this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: @D.Halsey If you measure the blueshift of M98, you get an indication of the force that's attracting it to us. Assuming it's gravitational, the amount of mass you need is far greater that you can account for from luminous matter in our galaxy or any other source.

Regarding the scatter of the diagram, I actually have no idea. You may be right that the majority of error comes from other sources like if there's a cloud of gas between us and the source, or unknown physics of SNe1a. The main point was that the peculiar velocities don't matter since we use many sources.

Comment: If you want to see a possible source of bias in SNe1a measurements, see pp. 18,23 of https://indico.desy.de/indico/event/18204/session/9/contribution/375/material/slides/0.pdf (or search for Rigault Age Bias Hubble Controversy)

Also, maybe I was confusing M98 with M31 (Andromeda, the nearest galaxy). I can't remember, but certainly my lecturer in our cosmology course mentioned a connection between blue-shifted galaxies and dark matter.

Comment: It would make more sense to talk about M31 being attracted to us, since as you say, it is our closest neighbor, whereas M98 has several much closer neighbors than us.

Comment: The notes on SN1a bias are very interesting. Thanks for linking them. It keeps alive the possibility that dark energy may be nothing, after all.

Comment: @D.Halsey You're right, I confused M98 with M31. No worries about the bias. Yes, maybe dark energy is nothing, but there are good theoretical reasons to think that it is something. The horizon problem is probably the most motivating (and its proposed solution-framework: inflation -- but you have to discard the hype). In any case, there was a paper published in Nature (https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02590) which aims at probing the Hubble diagram for redshifts z>1 using quasars. They claim to find a possibly anomaly with model without dynamical dark energy.